# Confidence in transcribed data by spot checking

Tags: confidence-interval, dataset

I have transcribed a data set by hand (1200 entries).

I want to estimate how accurate my transcription is.

I don't want to double check every entry, I just want to spot check enough to be confident that it is accurate.

When I say confident, I'm not sure I even know what the right criteria is for that. But I was thinking of an answer like "95% sure all data is correct" or "95% sure 90% of the data is correct" or something like that.

I know enough about statistics to know that it's too easy to go wrong if you don't really know what you are doing, so I am very reluctant to accept any of my analysis as valid.

What is the right way to calculate this?

Are there alternative questions I could be asking instead?

Comment: One question you need to resolve up front is how you will measure accuracy.  For instance, if your data consist of records and each record is a tuple of values, will you assess accuracy as the rate of correctly transcribed records or the rate of correctly transcribed values?  (The former is usually much lower than the latter.)  How will you assess subtler transcription errors such as failing to transcribe a record, multiple entries of the same record, and even multiple but differing entries of the same record? Will you distinguish errors in key fields from errors in data fields?

Comment: You could have an independent rater (or two) check a sample of your transcribed data, comparing the ground truth and your transcription. If each item is either correct or not (binary), then you could model Correct as a binomial RV and perform a variety of things, including Margin of Error and CIs. Worst case, you leave the data for a while (enough time for you to forget the details), then go back and re-transcribe a sample yourself.

Comment: @AlexL That is what I am asking, but how do I do that? Could you walk me through that?

Comment: @whuber the data is ordered. So, multiples and missing entries are the same as checking is record #327 = transcription #327. I was supposing I would simply generate a list of random record #'s and check to see how many were transcribed completely correct. E.G select 10 records at random and compare them. The result might be that only 9 are correct. What can I then infer about my overall transcription? How many should I check (assuming each check is correct) to have a level of confidence that they are all correct?

Comment: That has a straightforward answer, but raises an interesting question.  In some cases it can be cumbersome to look up and check randomly chosen records, whereas you might be able just as quickly to check entire batches of records, such as records that originally were transcribed from the same printed page of a report.  In such cases a stratified sampling plan will enable to use your time and resources more effectively.  What situation are you in?

Comment: @whuber If I am understanding you correctly, there are 4 different sections of data. Each section is printed on 3 pages with 4 columns of 25 each.

Comment: Unless you need some formal guarantees, you could avoid a lot of trouble and simply comprehensively check the first page in the first section, the last page in the last section, and maybe (if you felt the need) a randomly chosen page. That would take five to ten minutes.  If you display the data on-screen in the same format as they appear on a page, you can often compare a page with a screen very quickly and catch most mistakes.  This initial testing will give you a sense of your error rate.